# What would Environment.UserName return when used in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services

If I'm not wrong, window services are started when the computer boots. So, if I try to get `Environment.UserName` before a user has logged in, will it return something or will it throw an exception? If it is the former, what would it return?

Comment: What happened when you tried this?

Comment: In general, Services don't load a user profile. Whether or no a user has logged on, the Service won't see "a user" unless it goes looking more seriously than just looking at `Environment.UserName`

Comment: Even if a/multiple user(s) is logged on, a service calling Environment.Username won't get the logged on user, it gets the username of the account that runs the service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything running in Windows is executing as some account, and services are no different -- which account in specific depends on how the service was started and configured.

See here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/service-user-accounts

Comment: But, Services (generally) don't load a user profile. You can see the token (which may just be _Network Service_), but little else

Comment: @Flydog57 According to the linked Microsoft documentation: "The service control manager (SCM) automatically loads the user profile."

Comment: @MickyD You're right, I've updated my answer

Comment: Excellent, thanks for edit +1